# How do i put comma in the code to make the output look like this;i am Daystar,i am a boy, instead of;u am Daystari am a boy

Tags: java

i want the output to be; string,i am Daystar,I am a boy, but am getting; string i am Daystari am a boy

**My code**

```
    package tutorial;

    public class tutorial {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str1, str2;
       str1="i am Daystar";
       str2="i am a boy";
    
      System.out.println("string,"+str1 + str2);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply type:
`System.out.println("string," + str1 + "," + str2);`
As you already use it, you can easy add together string fragments by using the `+`-operator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use String format as below
Here 1 in `%1$s` indicates first argument

```
        String str1, str2;
        str1="i am Daystar";
        str2="i am a boy";

        String output = String.format("%1$s, %2$s", str1, str2);
        System.out.println(output);
```

**OUTPUT:** i am Daystar, i am a boy